# USB Wireless Mouse vs Bluetooth Mouse  

Tags: linux, mouse, bluetooth

What is best mouse for Linux machines Wireless via a USB dongle or Bluetooth?

Comment: Sorry Every one .. I am asking about best mouse is blue tooth or wireless  one ?

Comment: I guess this is not duplicate of both of it

Comment: Bluetooth is wireless.  This question doesn't make sense.  Please re-word it so that it does.

Comment: But wireless is not necessarily bluetooth...

Comment: Wireless Mouse and Bluetooth Mouse is not Same ..Just consider Wireless Mouse will work if its supports with out Bluetooth . Blue tooth mouse is different than Wireless

Comment: PLEASE POST REASON FOR DOWN VOTE ?

Comment: I'm guess wireless vs. bluetooth sounds like a stupid thing to ask, since bluetooth is a form of wireless. (I'm not the down-voter BTW). Perhaps you should improve the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally the reason I like Bluetooth is that it's built into most machines so you don't have the damn dongle that most wireless mice rely on.

One less thing to lose/forget, go wrong, have sticking out of your laptop waiting to get knocked when you're on a plane.

Maybe there are wireless mice which don't rely on a dongle using some other mechanism instead but most of the ones I've seen do.

Comment: logitechs wireless mice have a dongle which is smaller than the actual USB-connection, making this a total NON-issue.

Comment: @pavsaund - so because it's small it doesn't go wrong and you can't lose it?  I'd have thought that the fact it was small would make it easier to lose.

Comment: I've seen the afore-mentioned adapters.  They sit flush with the USB port when plugged in, and clip into the bottom of the mouse when not.  Beyond that, its your fault.

Comment: well, let me rephrase a little. By it being small, it never has to be removed from the USB port, thus explaining my previous post.

Comment: @Pavsaund - fair enough, it certainly minimises the issue though I'd say not having it would still be preferrable.

Comment: @pavsund -- going dongle-free frees up a valuable usb-slot (my mac laptop only has 2!)

Comment: Wireless mouse have much faster setup/connection speeds over Bluetooth mouse

Answer (score 1):

The non-bluetooth wireless is more likely to **just work**, as it'll be emulating USB (probably). However, depending on your distribution/expertise, that may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bluetooth, because using 2.4 GHz frequency. And have low susceptibility of interference.

Bluetooth

- specified frequency

Wireless

- frequency depends on the manufacturer